# How to add a page title using the Views module?

Tags: views, 7

I used the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to set up a new page. How do I add a title to it (as `<h1>`)?

I tried to add a title under the *Title* tab (where it says "This title will be displayed with the view, wherever...") but it doesn't add a title to my page.

Here is my exported view.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'nyheter';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Nyheter';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Nyheter';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Återställ';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['tags']['first'] = '« första';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['tags']['previous'] = '‹ föregående';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['tags']['next'] = 'nästa ›';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['tags']['last'] = 'sista »';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['view_mode'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['links'] = FALSE;
/* Fält: Innehåll: Titel */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Innehåll: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Innehåll: Publicerad */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Innehåll: Has taxonomy term */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['id'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_index';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['field'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['value'] = array(
  0 => '5',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['vocabulary'] = 'tags';

/* Display: Nyheter */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Nyheter', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['display_description'] = 'Nyheter visas här';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'nyheter';
$translatables['nyheter'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Nyheter'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Återställ'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« första'),
  t('‹ föregående'),
  t('nästa ›'),
  t('sista »'),
  t('Nyheter visas här'),
);
```

Notice that:

- The preview at the bottom is showing the title, but unfortunately the page doesn't
- The rendered page does not show any `<h1>` tag (or any other signs of a title in the code)
- I just noticed the title doesn't appear for other views as well; it's not just a problem with this view

Comment: You have some other issues there. There is a display name and a TITLE just above FORMAT label. If you have set that then SAVE your view and open it. The title SHOULD display.

Comment: Thanks for comment. The preview at the bottom of views-module is showing the title, but unfortunately the page doesn't.

Comment: Check the html source of the rendered page. Right click on the page and then select **Source** and then see if there is a h1 tag with class value as "page-header". If not then you are probably not on the same page as view.

Comment: The rendered page does not show any h1 tag (or any other signs of a title in the code). It must be the same page because under PAGE SETTINGS it says "/nyheter" which is right. Thanks for help, but sad this doesn't work.

Comment: Change the path to something totally new and then SAVE your views. Reload and access the new path/location. Update your Drupal version and Theme name please.

Comment: Did what you said but didn't work. =/

Comment: Well, in that case! find ***export view*** link on the right hand side of the view construction page (it is under edit view/name description) and then copy/paste your view code from there to your question so that others can see exactly what is wrong with your view.

Comment: I just imported your view into my Drupal and it displayed the following "Nyheter" as title of the page. I have accessed the view as myserveraddress/nyheter